# Convert netCDF files to csv

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf

I'm struggling to convert several Berkeley Earth netCDF files into CSV or another tabular format. I realize similar questions have been raised before, but I couldn't apply any of the solutions I came across.

For instance, [this dataset](http://berkeleyearth.lbl.gov/auto/Global/Gridded/Complete_TAVG_EqualArea.nc).

- `ncdump` from the netCDF utilities does not appear to generate an actual CSV file. I couldn't find any instruction on how to do so.
- I've tried loading the data into a `pandas` dataframe with `xarray.to_dataframe()`, but my notebook cannot allocate the required memory.

```py
In [1]: import xarray as xr

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: nc = xr.open_dataset('Complete_TAVG_Daily_EqualArea.nc')

In [4]: nc
Out[4]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (map_points: 5498, time: 50769)
Dimensions without coordinates: map_points, time
Data variables:
    longitude    (map_points) float32 ...
    latitude     (map_points) float32 ...
    date_number  (time) float64 ...
    year         (time) float64 ...
    month        (time) float64 ...
    day          (time) float64 ...
    day_of_year  (time) float64 ...
    land_mask    (map_points) float64 ...

In [5]: df = nc.to_dataframe()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 532. MiB for an array with shape (279127962,) and data type int16
```

- I've tried converting with `Panoply`. CSV export appears to work only to export a single variable (which I'd like to see as a column) into a single-line file.

I must be missing something. Can someone help me?

Comment: You're using a Jupyter Notebook? Have you tried running it as a standard script?

Comment: That makes no difference. Same result on Windows and Linux btw...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are missing is that netCDF is a much more sophisticated format than CSV. A netCDF file can contain multiple arrays of any shape and size. A CSV file can only contain a single array of maximal 2 dimensions (or a set of 1D arrays if they all have the same length). You therefore cannot simply convert any netCDF file to CSV.

Let's look at the example file you gave. I repeat the info here with my version of Xarray, which seems to be a bit more verbose...

```
In [16]: ds = xr.open_dataset('Complete_TAVG_EqualArea.nc')

In [17]: ds
Out[17]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (map_points: 5498, month_number: 12, time: 3240)
Coordinates:
    longitude    (map_points) float32 ...
    latitude     (map_points) float32 ...
  * time         (time) float64 1.75e+03 1.75e+03 1.75e+03 ... 2.02e+03 2.02e+03
Dimensions without coordinates: map_points, month_number
Data variables:
    land_mask    (map_points) float64 ...
    temperature  (time, map_points) float32 ...
    climatology  (month_number, map_points) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:          Berkeley Earth Internal Convention (based on CF-1.5)
    title:                Native Format Berkeley Earth Surface Temperature An...
    history:              16-Jan-2020 06:51:38
    institution:          Berkeley Earth Surface Temperature Project
    source_file:          Complete_TAVG.50985s.20200116T064041.mat
    source_history:       13-Jan-2020 17:22:52
    source_data_version:  ca6f26341938dae0ea7dd619bce6f15e
    comment:              This file contains Berkeley Earth surface temperatu...
```

There are three data variables (land_mask, temperature, climatology), plus three coordinate vectors (longitude, latitude, time). Perhaps you can include the coordinate vectors as the first row and column of a CSV file but even then this means you need at least three separate CSV files per netCDF file.

So for example for the `climatology` data frame you could write to CSV as follows:

```
In [31]: clim = ds['climatology']  

In [32]: clim.to_pandas().to_csv('clim.csv')
```

So `clim` is an `xarray.DataFrame` which, in principle, can be written to a CSV file. Unfortunately the `xarray.DataFrame` class does not have a `to_csv` method. However the `pandas.DataFrame` class does, so we first convert it to a pandas data frame. Look at its parameter documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to tweak the generated output file.

Comment: Thanks a million, that's a really clear explanation, and thanks for providing a more sensible approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a .nc to .csv using the CDO package suite.

Example code (you would need to edit some of the outputtab parameters:

```
cdo -outputtab,date,lon,lat,value infile.nc | awk 'FNR==1{ row=$2","$3","$4","$5;print row  } FNR!=1{ row=$1","$2","$3","$4; print row}' > outfile.csv
```